# How to send mock data using reducers in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created mock data for my react app just to test and check my redux if it is working properly or not. But it give an error of  "Cannot read property 'usersData' of undefined". I am bit confused what am I doing wrong as I am not good with redux.

Reducers:

```
    import types from './types';

    let defaultState = {
  usersDetail:{
    usersData: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: ''
  }
};
export default function usersReducer(state= defaultState, action= {}){
  let newState= {};
  switch (action.type){
    case types.INITIATE_USER_REQUEST:
      newState = {
        usersData: action.usersData,
        isFetching: action.isFetching,
        error: ''
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        usersDetail: {
          ...state.usersDetail, newState
        }
      };
    case types.RECEIVE_USER:
      newState = {
        usersData: action.usersData,
        isFetching: action.isFetching,
        error: ''
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        usersDetail:{
          ...state.usersDetail, newState
        }
      };
    case types.USER_ERROR:
      newState = {
        usersData:{},
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      };
      return{
        ...state,
        usersDetail:{
          ...state.usersDetail, newState
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Actions:

```
import types from './types';
//import {api} from "api";
import { usersDetails } from "./user-utilis";


const initiateUserRequest = (isFetching) => {
  return{
    type: types.INITIATE_USER_REQUEST,
    isFetching
  }
};
// const receiveUsers = (user, isFetching) => {
//   return {
//     type: types.RECEIVE_USER,
//     user,
//     isFetching
//   }
// };
// const errorUsers = (error) => {
//   return{
//     type: types.USER_ERROR,
//     error
//   }
// };
export const getUsers = (param1, param2) =>{
  //let url = 'www.api.com';

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initiateUserRequest(true));
    dispatch(usersDetails, false);

    //   api({
    //     url: url,
    //     method: 'GET'
    //   })
    //     .then(response=>{
    //       dispatch(receiveUsers(response.data, param1, param2), false)
    //     })
    //     .catch(err=>{
    //       dispatch(errorUsers("Something went wrong:"+ err.message))
    //     })
    // }
  }
};
```

As I am using mock data to check it not api integrated yet so I commented that section.

The store is connected and passed as a props into my component like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

//import components
import Users from '../../views/Users/Users.jsx'

//import actions
import {getUsers} from "./actions";

const UsersContainer = (props) => (
  <Users {...props}/>
);

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    usersDetail: state.usersReducer.usersDetail
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
  getUsers: (param1, param2) => dispatch(getUsers(param1, param2))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer);
```

I am passing this data as a props in my component like this.

```
<Table
                tableHeaderColor="primary"
                onEditUser={this.onEditUser}
                tableHead={["UserName", "Name", "Email", "Phone", "Zip", "Address", "status", "Mobile"]}
                tableData={usersDetail.usersData}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it rendering at all? I think the problem is that you are declaring an initial value for usersData as an array in your reducer, but you're referencing it as an object in your components. 
So by changing it initially to an object instead of an array inside your reducer should solve your problem i think.